# Guardar modificacion de ".xlsx" con openpyxl sin sobre escribir el documento actual

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

Editando la consulta anterior:

Mi problema va en lo siguiente:

1.- Ejecuto mi programa y en la interfaz gráfica, ingreso datos que serán guardados en un archivo de nombre seteado: “libro_registro.xlsx”.

2.- Al cerrar mi programa, y revisar mi archivo “libro_registro.xlsx”, mi data esta almacenada sin problemas.

3.- Ejecuto nuevamente mi programa, ingreso nueva información y esta se guarda efectivamente en el archivo “libro_registro.xlsx”, pero me sobre escribe al anterior. En otras palabras, pierdo toda la información que ingrese en el punto 1 y queda almacenada la nueva del punto 2.

Dejo un código especifico con el problema que tengo para que puedan replicar mi problema en sus equipos. El IDLE que utilizo es PyCharm.

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

```
import tkinter
import openpyxl

windows = tkinter.Tk()
windows.geometry("390x270")
ingreso = tkinter.StringVar()

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet_1 = wb.create_sheet("INGRESO")

def excel(registro):
    sheet_1.append(registro)
    wb.save('libro_registro.xlsx')

def getDato():
    nuevo_dato = ingreso.get()
    lista_excel = []
    lista_excel.append(nuevo_dato)

    # Llamando al excel:
    excel(lista_excel)

dato_label = tkinter.Label(windows, text="DATO")
dato_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
dato_entry = tkinter.Entry(windows, textvariable=ingreso)
dato_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

registrar_button = tkinter.Button(windows, text="Registrar", command=getDato)
registrar_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

windows.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si te entendí pero esa línea de código no tiene nada de malo. A qué te refieres con que quieres guardar ambos los cambios y no borrar lo anterior? Como se vería eso reflejado en un archivo?

En pocas palabras, simplemente define el nuevo nombre de archivo tú mismo. Probablemente basado en algun timestamp para que nada se sobreescriba.

Si eso no es tu problema te invito a que re-formules tu pregunta/problema.

Recomiendo tambien revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example